# Application Media types vs Text Media Types

Tags: java, java-ee

Хотел узнать какая разница между этими двумя Mime типами ?

1. Когда что лутше использовать ?
2. Зачем созданны два Mime типа для XML ?

Comment: Сначала при виде пары строк xml все обрадовались как все здорово и просто, удобно для чтения, Поэтому решили - пусть это будет текст. Удобно же. Потом столкнулись с реальностью. И сказали - без бутылки не разберёшься, так что пусть лучше будет всё-таки application.

Comment: Я тебя абсолютно не понял..

Comment: `If an XML document -- that is, the unprocessed, source XML document -- is readable by casual users, text/xml is preferable to application/xml. MIME user agents (and web user agents) that do not have explicit support for text/xml will treat it as text/plain, for example, by displaying the XML MIME entity as plain text. Application/xml is preferable when the XML MIME entity is unreadable by casual users.`

Comment: Не привело к пониманию.. Читал это. Есть ссылка на русском ?

Comment: `text/xml` - для xml, которые предназначены для чтения человеком. `application/xml` - для трудно-усвояемых человеком, для программной обработки. а так всем всё равно.

Comment: До профессионального перевода явно далеко.